# Passing Value from Trigger to Class & return value to Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

So I can pass a value to my class, but I then want to return a value to my trigger.  Is this even possible.

Here's the trigger (partially complete up to getting a value back at line 49:

```
trigger createProjectName on Case (before insert, before update) 
{
    String serviceType;
    ID i;
    Integer i2 = 0;
    Integer i3 = 0;
    Integer i1;
    String studyPeriodFed;
    String periodNameFed;
    String studyPeriodMaxFed;
    String studyPeriodMinFed;
    String periodNameMaxFed;
    List<String> studyYear = new List<String>();
    List<String> studyStateName = new List<String>();
    String stateName;

   for(Case ci : Trigger.new)
   {
       i = ci.Id;
       serviceType = ci.Service_Type__c;
   }

   List<Case_Intake_Period_of_Study__c> pOS = [SELECT Study_State__c,Study_Type__c,max(Study_Years__c) maxYr,min(Study_Years__c) minYr FROM Case_Intake_Period_of_Study__c Where Id =: i and Study_Years__c != null Group By Study_State__c, Study_Years__c ];

   For(Case_Intake_Period_of_Study__c s: pOS)
   {
        if(s[i1].maxYr==s[i1].minYr  && s.Study_Type__c=='Federal'  && i2==0)
        {
            studyPeriodFed = s[i].maxYr.substring(2,2);
            periodNameFed = studyPeriodFed + ' ' + ' FED';  
            i2 = i2 + 1;        

        }
        Else if(s[i].Study_Type__c=='Federal' && i2>0)
        {
            studyPeriodMaxFed = s[i].maxYr.substring(2,2);
            studyPeriodMinFed = s[i].minYr.substring(2,2);
            periodNameFed = studyPeriodMinFed + '-' + studyPeriodMaxFed + ' FED';
            i2 = i2 + 1; 
        }

        Else if(s[i].Study_Type__c=='State' && maxYr==minYr && i3==0)
        {
            studyYear.add(maxYr.substring(2,2));
            stateName = s[i].Study_State__c;

            returnStateAbbreviations f = new returnStateAbbreviations();
            f.returnStateAbbreviations(stateName);
            studyStateName[i] = abbr;  // I want the return here!!!line49
            i3 = i3 +1;
        }
    }    
 }
```

and here is the class:

```
 public with sharing class returnStateAbbreviations 
{  
    public string returnState(string stateName)
    { 
        String abbr;
        String stateAbbr;

        if(stateName=='Alabama')
        {
            stateAbbr = 'AL';           
        }
        else if(stateName=='Alaska')
        {
            stateAbbr = 'AK';
        }
        else if(stateName=='Arizona')
        {
            stateAbbr = 'AZ';
//etc ....

        else if(stateName=='Wyoming')
        {
            stateAbbr = 'WY';
        }

        abbr = stateAbbr;
        return abbr;        
    }  

}
```

Am I trying to do something impossible here.

Thanks in advance,

TDM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the function static, in which case you can call it without having to create an instance of it. Regardless, to get to the main point, you can simply assign the *return value* from the function back to the variable you want to save it in to:

```
studyStateName[i] = f.returnStateAbbreviations(stateName);
```

There's plenty more efficient ways of doing this, including one of my favorite techniques:

```
public string returnStateAbbreviations(String stateName) {
    return new Map<String, String> {
        'Alabama' => 'AL',
        'Alaska' => 'AK',     
        // other data
    }.get(stateName);
}
```

You could also use a Custom Setting to use an indexed cache that's easy to access, but I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Works like a charm.  Thanks for the tip on how to jettison the If statements.  The mapping is more elegant.